# What is the equivalent of C# "tag" property in objective-c cocoa-touch for a UITableViewCell?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I was wondering if I can store a data object in a certain tag associated with a tableViewCell, for ease of access to the data associated logically to that cell.

So is there a property to store the data object in? for a TableViewCell?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tag on a UITableViewCell (and on many other Cocoa classes) stores only an integer.  You could use it to store some predefined constant, e.g.

```
myCell.tag = TAG_CELL_HEADER;
```

or you could use a numbering scheme to save the model ID that corresponds to the cell, e.g.

```
myCell.tag = TAG_RECORD_OFFSET + record.rowid;
```

In general, you can keep an array of data and use the tag as an index into it.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike C#, the `tag` property in UIKit controls takes an Integer data type. Currently, there is no equivalent to the C# tag property in Cocoa.

**EDIT**

Each UITableViewCell has a cell "identifier" (NSString). It may be beneficial for you to log the section and row in a formatted string for each cell, or use another type of ID scheme.

This can be set in the delegate method:

`-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyIdentifierString";
```

Comment: As there's no reason for it in Cocoa. It works perfectly without it.

Comment: @georg
well it works perfectly without it? yeah "IT" does. A car would run perfectly with Wooden wheels... if you make the road paved with layers of caoutchouc closing on a certain gas :)

Comment: @LolaRun: No really, Cocoa is structured in a way that makes tags in almost all instances unnecessary.

Comment: I read your edit, but i was asking if i was a able to store a data object in the tag of the cells, and since in the other response i can have an int id pointer to use in parallel with an array of data objects, is still more useful than the string identifier of the cell. Thanks a lot